# Implicit inequality

Tags: real-analysis, inequalities

Let $A,B,d\ge 1$ and suppose that $x\ge0$ satisfies
$$  x^{\frac{d+1}{d}}
  \le
  Ax+B.
\qquad(*)
$$
I can show that $(*)$ implies the bound
$$
  x< d(A^d+B).
\qquad(**)
$$

Questions: (1) Can a better bound than $(**)$ be obtained? (2) Can such bounds be easily derived from some general "master" theorem?

Comment: Is the initial condition *greater than or equal to $1$* only imposed on $d$, or on  $A$ and $B$ too?

Comment: on all 3 -- otherwise, the claim is false

Comment: To improve a bit your bound you may multiply $(*)$ by $\lambda ^{\frac{ d+1}{d}}$, deducing a family of $(*)_\lambda$ for $\lambda x$, with $\lambda$ in the range of validity of your initial bound (that is, with corresponding $A_\lambda\ge1, B_\lambda\ge1$). Then you may optimize w.r.to $\lambda$  the corresponding bound on $x$ given by $(**)_\lambda$

Answer (score 2):

I assume $d$ is an integer. 
Let $x=y^d$, then the inequality takes form:
$$y^{d+1} \leq Ay^d+B.$$
It holds for $y\leq Y$, where $Y$ is the largest zero of the polynomial $y^{d+1} - Ay^d-B$.

There is a number of [known bounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Bounds_on_all_roots) for polynomial zeros. For example, Cauchy's bound gives $Y\leq 1+\max(A,B)$ implying that $x\leq (1+\max(A,B))^d$. Under scaling we can also get
$$x\leq ((B/A)^{1/d}+A)^d.$$
Alternatively, Hölder's inequality for $k=d$ gives
$$x\leq 1+(A^{d/(d-1)}+B^{d/(d-1)})^{d-1},$$
and so on.

Comment: Is this bound better than (**)?

Comment: If $B<<A$, then Yes.

Comment: Following this idea, and putting $y:=1/u$, the problem translates into a bound for the smallest root of a trinomial equation $u+u^q=c$, for which however there is a power series solution  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249060/series-solution-of-the-trinomial-equation

Comment: @PietroMajer: Yes, this is in the same venue as https://mathoverflow.net/q/32261